# SharePoint Migration with items read only properties

Tags: sharepoint, properties, migration, readonly

I have SP 2007 and I will install a new SP 2010 farm.

I want to migrate most of the data (Documents, SP Pages, Lists, Images, Tasks, etc.).

I am building a tool for this, but I need to move the items properties as well such as ( created by, modified by, etc.).

How can I do such thing? The object model is not working. I checked this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22516/change-read-only-attribute-from-sharepoint-2010-list-column 
but its nor working on the ID and modified By (those fields what I tested).

I know it's doable because there is a tool do such thing, but I cant buy it.
Do I need to update the list from data base? 
And how can I find where the list items is saved?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write a custom tool. There are two approaches for a SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010 migration:

1. In place migration
2. Attach content database upgrade

See [Upgrade and Migration for SharePoint Server 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee517214) for more information.

For instance when updating via *attach content database upgrade* you have to execute the follwing PowerShell command which will upgrade the content for you:

```
Mount-SPContentDatabase -Name <DatabaseName> -DatabaseServer <ServerName> -WebApplication <URL> [-Updateuserexperience]
```

I strongly recommend to read this paper (provided by Microsoft) to get information how to upgrade to SharePoint 2010:

[Attach databases and upgrade to SharePoint Server 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc263299.aspx)

**Even if you do not want to migrate all the content, I suggest to use to official upgrade path and remove the content that should not be migrated.**